# Access to an old paper of Obata

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to access the following paper of Morio Obata:

*Conformal changes of Riemannian metrics on a Euclidean sphere*, in "Differential Geometry -- In honor of K. Yano", 1972, pp. 347--353: MR Y. Katsurada, 48#2937

Does anyone have access to an online version of the article? I can't seem to find the article or book online, and my university library does not have the reference.

Comment: My university library has a copy. I'll be able to get a scan of it later this week; you can find my contact information on the homepage linked in my profile.

Comment: Update: I have it now, so if you send me an email, I am happy to send it you.